# I want "divs" of second row to be arranged right below first row of "divs" but they getting arranged leaving a gap

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

**CSS:**
After clicking the button, you will see the divs getting created in line. I want "divs" of second row to be arranged right below first row of "divs" but they getting arranged leaving a gap. The text alignments inside the "divs" shouldn't get disturbed.

```js
function myFunction() {
  addWordToList("Apple", "Fruit");
}

    var spno = 0;

    function addWordToList(Word, Meaning)
    {
      spno++;
      var dv = document.createElement("DIV");
      document.body.appendChild(dv);
      dv.setAttribute("class", "tooltip");
      dv.setAttribute("id", "pilldiv"+spno);
      document.getElementById("pilldiv"+spno).textContent=Word;
      dv.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', "&nbsp;");
      var spn = document.createElement("SPAN");
      dv.appendChild(spn);
      spn.setAttribute("class", "tooltiptext");
      spn.setAttribute("id", "spn"+spno);
      document.getElementById("spn"+spno).textContent=Meaning;
    }
```

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 1.6em;
  margin: 4em auto;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10%/50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #11998E , #38EF7D);
  font-weight: 700;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click to Create Divs</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the tooltip's css to following:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  height: 1.6em;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 10%/50%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #11998E , #38EF7D);
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

i.e. remove  "margin: 4em auto;". Due to margin, the actual height of the box is getting increased and creating the gap.